# jpa delete query error: unexpected token

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, named-query

I want to delete a list of items and I defined the following query for the Entity Email:

@NamedQuery(name = Email.namedQueryDeleteOldEmails,
query = "DELETE FROM Email e where e.creationDate <= :creationDate")

When I execute it, I have the following error:
2012-10-26 12:45:25,570 ERROR [SGVISTA] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:1: unexpected token: Email
line 1:1: unexpected token: Email

Does anybody know what is wrong with my query?
Thank you very much

Comment: you are missing double quotes around the name of the NamedQuery, is that just a typo? name = "Email.namedQueryDeleteOldEmails"

Answer (score 0):

@NamedQuery(name ="Email.namedQueryDeleteOldEmails", query = "DELETE FROM Email e where e.creationDate <= :creationDate")

use the named name inside double quotes it will work